# Smoother with categorical x?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having an issue where I'd like to be able to have a categorical x value in a scatter plot with a smoother line.

My data (pHlt):

```
 age  means
18-24 2.170
25-29 2.396
30-34 2.691
35-39 3.004
40-44 3.517
45-49 4.096
50-54 4.814
55-59 5.445
60-64 5.371
65-69 4.889
70-74 4.947
75-79 5.270
80+ 5.664
```

```
ggplot(pHlt, aes(y = means, x = age)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=means, x=age)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2, 6))
```

The output is a scatter plot lacking a smoother. I figured this was because x is categorical.

So, I went ahead and changed "age" to numeric, removing the range of values and instead having the lowest age (18, 25, 30, etc). This makes things work, which is fine, but ideally I'd include the age categories. Is there any way to keep the categories, or is this my best option?

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to connect the points between age ranges, you could use `geom_path(aes(group = 1))`

Answer (score 1):

You can coerce age to a factor first and subsequently to a numeric. This way you can still display the categories.

```
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~age,    ~means,
  "18-24", 2.170,
  "25-29", 2.396,
  "30-34", 2.691,
  "35-39", 3.004,
  "40-44", 3.517,
  "45-49", 4.096,
  "50-54", 4.814,
  "55-59", 5.445,
  "60-64", 5.371,
  "65-69", 4.889,
  "70-74", 4.947,
  "75-79", 5.270,
  "80+",   5.664
) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = means, x = age)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y = means, x = as.numeric(as.factor(age)))) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2, 6))
```